# error: not recognized as

Tags: batch-file, exe, batch-processing

I have an exe file. I want to run it several times consecutively one after another.

I tried this;

```
for /L %%N in (1,1,5) do ran.exe %%N
```

I tried this also

```
for /L %%N in (1,1,%1) do ran.exe %%N
```

I got an error like this

"for is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

What can I do?
I run batch file from cmd and also from windows by double clicking

Comment: Leaving the fact that it is an infinite loop (from 1 to 5 in steps of 0), how have you tried this? Maybe a stupid question, but the error message is unusual.

Comment: yes I am sure. Its for "for"

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  type this at a cmd prompt and tell us if it shows the help **FOR /?**

Comment: do you use `CALL FOR..` construction somewhere?

Comment: I tried this from cmd and it worked;  "for  /L %i in (1,1,5) do ran"

Comment: Then check your batch file.  There is either a typo or the error message was not copy and pasted and it is subtly different.

Comment: Ok it was a typo. I guess aAfter for there should be a space . Now finally this one worked  ın batch file   "for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do ran "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved:
Here is the solution

for /L %i in (1,1,5) do ran